# Conditional count inside query in Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am getting teachers information from several tables using the query below. In **selectteacehrs** table there are cells `user_id` and `head_id`, a user/teacher may have some values in other rows those could be found depending on `head_id`.

For example:

```
$distributed = SelectedTeacehr::where('head_id', $teacher->id)->sum('no_of_sheet');
```

I just need this count inside the query below.

```
$teacehrs = DB::select("
            SELECT
                users.name as ex_name,
                users.id as id,
                districts.name as ex_district,
                thanas.name as ex_thana,
                users.account_br_rout as ex_bank_routing_no,
                selectteacehrs.no_of_sheet as sheet_count,
                selectteacehrs.head_id as head,
                subjects.cost_per_sheet as per_sheet_cost,
                LTRIM(RTRIM(subjects.name)) as ex_sub,
                ((thanas.ta_cost+thanas.da_cost)+(selectteacehrs.no_of_sheet*subjects.cost_per_sheet)) as total_cost
            FROM selectteacehrs
            INNER JOIN users ON users.id = selectteacehrs.user_id
            INNER JOIN thanas ON thanas.code = users.thana_code
            INNER JOIN districts ON districts.code = users.district_code
            INNER JOIN subjects ON selectteacehrs.sub_code = subjects.code
            {$where}
            LIMIT {$from},{$perpage}
        ");
```